# The right way to use MbedTLS's TLS 1.3 client?

Tags: c, linux, ssl, tls1.3, mbedtls

On any x86_64 Linux. Current development branch `a021d63bf7f5b33fc2e4b567a8db99de049318f2`.

```bash
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls
cd mbedtls
make -j$(nproc) CFLAGS=-DMBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_3=1

echo "========== curl www.google.com =========="
curl -vvvk --tlsv1.3 https://www.google.com > /dev/null

echo "========== mbedtls www.google.com =========="
programs/ssl/ssl_client2 server_name=www.google.com server_port=443 ca_path=/etc/ssl/certs/ force_version=tls13
```

The curl runs well, but mbedtls's `programs/ssl/ssl_client2` seems unable to make request with TLS 1.3 to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) . It runs normal if `force_version=tls12`.

```
========== mbedtls www.google.com ==========
build version: Mbed TLS 3.5.1 (build 50659584)

  . Seeding the random number generator... ok
  . Loading the CA root certificate ... ok (0 skipped)
  . Loading the client cert. and key... ok (key type: RSA)
  . Setting up the SSL/TLS structure... ok
  . Connecting to tcp/www.google.com/443... ok
  . Performing the SSL/TLS handshake... failed
  ! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x7200

Last error was: -0x7200 - SSL - An invalid SSL record was received
```

And here [my testing on GitHub Actions](https://github.com/kkocdko/utils4linux/actions/runs/7417207949/job/20183339300).

So, how to use MbedTLS's TLS 1.3 client? Is this a bug or not? I see many bugs about tls 1.3 in MbedTLS's issues list.

Answer (score 2):

Define `MBEDTLS_SSL_TLS1_3_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1` is required.

```bash
make -j$(nproc) CFLAGS="-DMBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_3=1 -DMBEDTLS_SSL_TLS1_3_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1"
```